# Issue with extra space added before file insertion using InsertFile method

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am having an issue when inserting a file into a word document(main document) using the InsertFile method using a Word VBA Macro I created, where it is inserting an extra space to the left of the paragraph I am trying to insert into the document. The document I amd trying to insert into is set up with multiple bookmarks that either deletes or retains paragraphs and is supposed to retain the spacing between the paragraphs. For whatever reason When inserting a file it adds not only that extra space but also adds extra lines after the paragraph too. Just so you know I have space symbols enabled which word represents with dots.

Below is the structure of the main document that I am inserting all of the text into (I scratched out text from a paragraph that is always in the main document, anonymized the text):
[image]

The reason why the middle paragraph bookmark isn't set to the same line as the previous paragraph is because when I try to insert a line break before inserting the file it doesn't add the line breaks and just prints the text in the previous paragraph when i really want them seperated. Wierd thing is the line breaks work for the other paragraphs that are not inserting text from a file...

The file I am attempting to insert is just a word document which consists of one paragraph of text where the space before the first word of the paragraph is not present but when inserted that space is added. Here is an image of the issue with the main document after all of the insertions(anonymized the text with explanations of the issue):

[image]

My code first sets the bookmark to a range variable, then sets the text of the bookmark to blank(essentially deleting the bookmark), then uses that range variable to insert either a file, hardcoded text or a database field. The code works fine for the text or database field but adds that extra space when inserting text from a file. Here is the code I am using to insert the file into my main document:

```
 BookmarkRange.InsertFile (FiletoInsert)
```

My question is there a way to avoid this extra space? Or if not do I just need to figure out the range for that extra space and then delete it out after the insertion? Let me know if you need more information to answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't duplicate the space you're seeing when you insert a file, unless that file has a space as its first character.

When you insert a file, the last character inserted will be a paragraph mark, which explains why the text following what you insert "moves down". If you're getting more than one new paragraph then the file you're inserting contains multiple "empty" paragraphs at the end.

There are two possibilities for bringing in the file and suppressing that paragraph mark:

1. Bookmark the text in the file that you want to bring in. `InsertFile` has a parameter `Range` that lets you specify a bookmark name in the file and inserts only the bookmark's content:

   ```
   rngBookmark.InsertFile "C:\Test\Test_Centered.docx", "test3"
   ```
2. Remove the paragraph after inserting the file. `Range.InsertFile` leaves the range at its starting point. So a second range is needed to mark the point that follows the inserted content.

   ```
   Sub InsertFileNoLeadingSpace()
     Dim rngBookmark As Word.Range, rngAfterBookmark As Word.Range

     Set rngBookmark = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("test1").Range
     Set rngAfterBookmark = rngBookmark.Duplicate
     rngAfterBookmark.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
     'Move one character further so that the Range is beyond the inserted content
     rngAfterBookmark.MoveStart wdCharacter, 1
     rngBookmark.InsertFile "C:\Test\Test_Centered.docx"
     'Move it back by two in order to pick up the inserted paragraph mark
     rngAfterBookmark.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -2
     'If the position after the inserted content is required after deleting the paragraph mark
     'this next line is necessary because deleting the paragraph mark
     'sets rngAfterBookmark to another location - it doesn't remain where you'd think
     Set rngBookmark = rngAfterBookmark.Duplicate
     rngAfterBookmark.Delete
     rngBookmark.Select
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Thanks Cindy, I was not aware of the extra parameter for the InsertFile method, this has resolved the issue. Also the MoveStart/MoveEnd methods helped me clean up the extra lines that were being inserted.